# asp.net: FormsAuthentication.SignOut() doesn't clear auth cookie

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

I want to be able to track user logins and logouts on my site.

I wrote an http module for that.

I can detect a login no problem. Logouts, however, I'm having a trouble with.

My initial thought was to check for the destruction of the cookie inside Application_EndRequest handler.
That does no good, because after the call to FormsAuthentication.SignOut(), request cookie collection still contains the auth cookie.

```
// In Application_EndRequest

if (httpRequest.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = httpRequest.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    // Doesn't work. "authCookie" is always non-empty
    if (authCookie == null || authCookie.Value == "") 
    {
        //logout detected
    }
}
else 
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = httpRequest.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null) 
    {
        //login detected
    }
}
```

If this is not the right approach, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` and `httpRequest.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]` in same request?

If so, the cookie will still be valid, because `SignOut()` could not make the cookie invalid in the current request.

You will need to test whether cookie is valid or not in separate request. Even then, calling `Request.IsAuthenticated` is enough, because you do not need to call `Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]` explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I call both of those in the same request.
You're suggesting to check for the cookie in separate request. But won't the cookie always be null? A null cookie doesn't necessarily mean a logout. An anonymous user doesn't have a cookie for example.

Comment: `You're suggesting to check for the cookie in separate request.` ***Yes.*** `won't the cookie always be null?` we cannot directly delete a cookie inside a client computer, once it is set. However, we can set expiration date to a past date, and it becomes invalid. Then browser will clean up those expired cookies later. Calling `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` is enough; I won't worry about cookie being deleted or not.